# ResizeMode prop for video in Expo ReactNative Project is not resizing my video. I am using expo-av package to display video

Tags: react-native, web, frontend, expo

This is for the web development btw, not for Ios or Android

So this is my view

```
<View style={styles.fullView}>
   <Video shouldPlay isLooping resizeMode="cover" source={require("./res/bg.mp4")} style={{flex: 1}}/>     
</View>
```

And This is my Stylesheet

```
fullView: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  heading: {
    color: 'white',
    marginBottom: 100,
    fontSize: 35,
  },

  input: {
    padding: 6,
    fontSize: 16,
    width: 200,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
  },

  bgcolor: {
    backgroundColor: '#33373861',
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: 10,
  },

  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FBC1F0',
    margin: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    padding: 10,
    height: 45,
    width: 200,
  },

  image: {
    flex: 1,

  }
```

What I am getting is this
[image]

What I need is the whole video on screen
[image]

I have tried to use resizeMode with cover,contain,stretch,repeat none of them work

Its Like the resizeMode is not recognized itself.

But when I change the height and width in stylesheet the video frame resizes But the video doesn't

Video Resolution is 3840 x 2160.

I want it to resize the video to screen size or adjust accordingly

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered this happens for web only because the `Video` html element is **absolutely position** for some reason.

If you add the following line to your `onReadyForDisplay` function it will fix it:

```
import { Video } from 'expo-av';

<Video
  style={styles.video}
  source={{
    uri: 'http://path/to/file',
  }}
  useNativeControls={true}
  resizeMode="contain"
  onReadyForDisplay={videoData => {
    videoData.srcElement.style.position = "initial"
  }}
/>
```